# Trigger gitlab pipeline only when in specific branches

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

### What I have so far

I have configured gitlab ci/cd pipeline for my project. So I have used base template which has 2 stages, build & package:

The build stage builds the project and creates a jar file.
The package stage creates an image and store it in the container registry. A .gitlab-ci.yml file has been created.

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - package

build:
  image: gradle:5.6.1-jdk11
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle clean build -x test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar

package:
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-project/sample .
    - docker login -u $CI_DOCKER_USERNAME -p $CI_DOCKER_PASSWORD registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push rregistry.gitlab.com/my-project/sample
```

### My problem

I don't want to trigger a build for all every branch. I want to trigger only in the development- and master-branch.

Is there anyway we can do that at project level instead of adding `only` in each stage?

Answer (score 6):

The only way to limit when jobs are created is by using `only/except`in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.

To not have to write so much text, you can use `extends` and also sometimes yaml anchors. More info here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends

and here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors

An example of how `extends` can be used:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

.only-master-and-develop:
  only:
   - master
   - development

stages:
  - build
  - package

build:
  extends: .only-master-and-develop
  image: gradle:5.6.1-jdk11
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle clean build -x test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/libs/*.jar

package:
  extends: .only-master-and-develop
  stage: package
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/my-project/sample .
    - docker login -u $CI_DOCKER_USERNAME -p $CI_DOCKER_PASSWORD registry.gitlab.com
    - docker push rregistry.gitlab.com/my-project/sample
```

(I haven't tested this file, please let me know if there's something wrong with it.)

Comment: this script actually not working... so i had to add only in both stages. It worked in gitlan-runner in my local thats i made it as answer. But when build get fired from commit it is failing because of invalid yaml and I even checked with lint on gitlab.com and it is also saying same.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I tried it myself now, and I got a yaml error because of a missing colon. I fixed it in the code example I gave. Does it work after adding the colon?

Answer (score 6):

You should specify the target branch using via $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "<your_branch_name>".

```yaml
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      something regarding the project..

    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"'
      something regarding the project..
```

I hope above example can help anyone!

Also [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variables-in-ruleschanges) is the documentation for these types of questions.

Comment: I think this is better: `if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'`, so if your master branch is main or master it doesn't matter.